# how to handle "Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text "?

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv

Below there are two successive lines of csv:

`"e90d18e0-ffe2-499c-9e46-3e7f15534ae8","Chandra Chekuri","40.09954372811568","-88.250470161438","Great part for running\0walking, tennis, pickle ball, volley ball, and Jarlings across!","Entertainment"`

`"cbef09e1-3e64-407a-b60d-22d6c6e1f589","Jingyi Yang","40.10999424873548","-88.2291090488434","Cocomero has the best ice cream.","Restaurant"`

Error message:

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text: [ and Jarlings across!,Entertainment cbef09e1-3e64-407a-b60d-22d6c6e1f589,Jingyi Yang,40.109994248...]`

I don't quite understand what and why exception might throw here. My format looks like correct for me. How to solve this error, please?

StackTrace:

```
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: Unterminated quoted field at 
    end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text: [ and Jarlings 
    across!,Entertainment
    cbef09e1-3e64-407a-b60d-22d6c6e1f589,Jingyi Yang,40.109994248...]
        at com.opencsv.CSVIterator.next(CSVIterator.java:69)
        at com.opencsv.CSVIterator.next(CSVIterator.java:18)
 Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvMalformedLineException: Unterminated quoted field at end of CSV line. Beginning of lost text: [ and Jarlings across!,Entertainment
    cbef09e1-3e64-407a-b60d-22d6c6e1f589,Jingyi Yang,40.109994248...]
        at com.opencsv.CSVReader.primeNextRecord(CSVReader.java:245)
        at com.opencsv.CSVReader.flexibleRead(CSVReader.java:610)
        at com.opencsv.CSVReader.readNext(CSVReader.java:204)
        at com.opencsv.CSVIterator.next(CSVIterator.java:67)
            ... 7 more
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: I see `\0`, which is peculiar.

Comment: @MCEmperor I could delete that as I saw this could be escaped.

Comment: Your separator is a comma, which you also use in one of your fields. That won't end up well...

Comment: @Slevin Hi, the comma in field is ok, right? As long as I double-quoted it.

Comment: CSV just determines the separators, it won't watch out quotes, at least not when not using quotes as separators.

Comment: Please provide a runnable example, including the precise csv library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your separator is a comma, which you also use in one of your fields. Either use an other spearator like a semicolon, or escape the commas within the fields.

```
"e90d18e0-ffe2-499c-9e46-3e7f15534ae8";"Chandra Chekuri";"40.09954372811568";"-88.250470161438";"Great part for running\0walking, tennis, pickle ball, volley ball, and Jarlings across!";"Entertainment"
```